# How to store sessions in DynamoDB using Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

We are using rails 3.2.x, I want to store our session in DynamoDB. I tried the 'aws-sessionstore-dynamodb' gem but I don't know where to specify the credentials. We use PostgreSQL in our database.yml so I don't think that I'll have to specify it there. Any thoughts?

I already ran the generate command below but I still can't figure out where to put the AWS Credentials and the endpoint of the DynamoDB.

```
rails generate sessionstore:dynamodb
```

This is the github page of the gem I'm trying to use. https://github.com/aws/aws-sessionstore-dynamodb-ruby

If you are storing your sessions in DynamoDB using another gem, I'm also open to that.

Answer (score 0):

The `aws-sessionstore-dynamodb` gem uses version 1 of the `aws-sdk` gem. You can configure your credentials for this in a Rails config initializer:

```
# RAILS_ROOT/config/initializers/aws-sdk-v1.rb
AWS.config(
  access_key_id: '...',
  secret_access_key: '...',
  region: 'us-west-2',
)
```

Simply replace the placeholders with your credentials and your chosen AWS region (us-west-2 is geographically close to me).